# Firebase Storage Rules using flutter (or Android)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I use flutter with firebase to save my images, and I use my app as an authenticated firebase user.

**Rules first use case:**

```
rules_version = '2';
firebase.storage service {
   match / b / {bucket} / o {
     match / {allPaths = **} {
       allow read, write: if true;
     }
   }
}
```

Here, to display the images I can use the download url of the photos using:
`await ref.getDownloadURL ();`
example:
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/project_name/o/images%2Fimage_name.jpg?alt=media&token=TOKEN
But also I can use the direct url of the photo (**without token**) and it works perfectly.
example:
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/project_name/o/images%2Fimage_name.jpg?alt=media

**Rules second use case:**

```
rules_version = '2';
firebase.storage service {
   match / b / {bucket} / o {
     match / {allPaths = **} {
       allow read, write: if request.auth! = null;
     }
   }
}
```

here I can use `await ref.getDownloadURL ();`
but i can't use the image url (hard coded)

**My question :**
why we use the rules of firebase storage (if request.auth! = null;) if the `ref.getDownloadURL ()` is accessible even in a private browser and it does not require an authenticated user, however the url of the image (without token) is not accessible even if you are a firebase authenticated user?

Answer (score 0):

That's just the way that download URLs work.  They are designed to bypass all security rules.  Rules only apply the code running in web and mobile apps that use the Firebase SDK to read and write data in the storage bucket.  If you don't want full public access to a file, then don't use a download URL.

Comment: thanks for the reply, that's clear.
so what should i use , if i don't want full piblic access to my data ?

Comment: If you need to share a URL, you will need to write your own backend API that somehow checks to see if the person or entity making the request is allowed to do so.